# Regex - Numbers starting at 60.00 with no upper limit with max of 2 decimals

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx for a numeric value that starts at 60.00 and has no upper limit.

I have used the below RegEx for numbers between 0.00 and 60.00, but now I need a similar expression for all numbers over 60.00 with 2 decimal places

```
^(?=.)(?:(?:(?:0|[1-5]?\d)?(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)|60(?:[.,]00?)?)$
```

Comment: Hi Rafael and welcome here. Such complex patterns are so hard to understand and to debug, that a test set and expected results could help :)

Comment: Did you mean `^(?:[6-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})$`? That is, 60 and more?

Comment: Hey, so basically im applying this to a form where I want users to only be able to submit values over 60 and being this a currency field, it needs to allow for two decimal places.

Good values:
60.01
88.99
109
67
bad values:
60
45.88
8
the numbers accepted will start at 60.01 and have no upper ceiling ( or at least a very high one)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^(?!60(?:\.00?)?$)(?:[6-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

Or, if you cannot afford lookaheads:

```
^(?:60(?:\.(?:0?[1-9]|[1-9][0-9]))|(?:6[1-9]|[7-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]{2,})(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)$
```

See the [regex demo #1](https://regex101.com/r/D1bB2P/1) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/D1bB2P/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?!60(?:\.00?)?$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if the string is `60`, `60.0` or `60.00`
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `[6-9][0-9]` - `60` to `99` number
  - `|` - or
  - `[1-9][0-9]{2,}` - a digit from `1` to `9` and then two or more digits (`100` and more)
- `)` - end of the group
- `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` - an optional sequence of a `.` and one or two digits
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thanks for this, it works from 60 upwards but also accepts the 60 itself when it should only start at 60.01, is it possible to make that happen? or to change my other regex ^(?=.)(?:(?:(?:0|[1-5]?\d)?(?:[,.]\d{1,2})?)|60(?:[.,]00?)?)$ to not include 60 and only go up to 59.99? thank you so much for your help, this has already been great